# How to set up POP3 from Google Apps to Google Apps?

Tags: google-apps-email, email-forwarding, pop3

I have Google Apps standard edition with two accounts - account A and account B.

I want to **redirect** all emails from one account (account A) to the other one (account B). Works nicely but... when Redmine sends an email as user account A via Google SMTP where the authentication is gone as account A the email appears in account A inbox but is not forwarded to account B.

So I tried to get new emails from account A via POP3 but I couldn't make it work.

Any suggestions how to make POP3 from Google Apps standard edition work.

Or is there any other solution to what I want to achieve?

---

I don't want to user one account for everything as I have to tell Redmine my password. So I created special Redmine account.

Comment: anybody would have some clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Username: username@yourdomain.com
- POP3 server: pop.gmail.com
- Use SSL: Yes
- Port: 995