# Google Apps Email POP3 denied access error message

Tags: google-workspace, pop3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up POP3 from Google Apps to Google Apps?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7063/how-to-set-up-pop3-from-google-apps-to-google-apps)

I’m trying to get emails from one account to another, both from the same domain (Google Apps Business), but while trying to do this I’m getting the famous `Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password`.

username: **is correct**
password: **is correct**
POP3 server: mail.MYDOMAIN.com (Is this OK?)

Answer (score 0):

- Username: username@yourdomain.com
- POP3 server: pop.gmail.com
- Use SSL: Yes
- Port: 995